# Javascript module.export struct of function pointers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm getting the following when I run my node app:

```
Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

I have the following in my app.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()

// imports
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var api = require('./api/controllers/apiController.js');

// serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

// support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// support encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

console.log(api);    

app.post('/api/newFoo', api.newFoo);
```

And in my apiController file, I export the following:

```
function newFoo(req, res, next) {

}

function getFoo(req, res, next) {

}

function newBar(req, res, next) {

}

function getBar(req, res, next) {

}

module.exports = {
  newFoo: newFoo,
  getFoo: getFoo,
  newBar: newBar,
  getBar: getBar
};
```

What am I doing wrong in exporting my functions as a dictionary, where they are not being recognized as function pointers?

It works fine when I do the following for each function:

```
module.exports.newFoo = function(req, res, next) {};
```

And my console output for console.log(api.newFoo) is [Function] and gives me typeof as "function" but the original method in question results in [newFoo : Function] which returns typeof as "undefined"

Comment: Check on what `typeof api.newFoo` is.  Also do `console.log(api)` and see what you have.  There isn't anything obviously wrong with your code so something is wrong that is not disclosed here.  You need to do a little debugging on your end to gather some clues.

Comment: On printing to console, all looks fine. I wonder whats happening in the router that is throwing the error. Good to know that the code itself is functioning. Thanks!

1:45:07 PM web.1 |  { newFoo: [Function: newFoo],
1:45:07 PM web.1 |    getFoo: [Function: getFoo],
1:45:07 PM web.1 |    newBar: [Function: newBar],
1:45:07 PM web.1 |    getBar: [Function: getBar] }

Comment: That looks like the `newFoo` property contains an array, not a function reference.  That also doesn't look like normal `console.log()` output so it's not so easy for me to interpret.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking when I originally wrote that answer of mine, but indeed, there's nothing wrong with the code. See: http://d.pr/i/h9Oh and http://d.pr/i/I1Mm

Comment: When I implement the export using the method that worked: module.exports.newFoo = function(req, res, next) {}; 

My console output is newFoo: [Function] and gives me typeof as "function" but the method in question results in newFoo: [newFoo : Function] which returns typeof as "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

> server.js main file runing on {node server.js}

```
`const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var api = require('./apiController.js');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

console.log(api.getFoo); //--->[Function: newFoo] worked for me 
console.log(typeof(api.getFoo)); //===> function
app.post('/api/getFoo', api.getFoo);
app.listen(port) `
```

> by listening on an port have tried with postman also it worked for me

---

> apiController.js file this is requiring on the server

```
function getFoo(req, res, next) {
console.log("2st function");
}
module.exports = {
  getFoo: getFoo
}
```

- node      -v  8.1.2
- npm       -v  5.0.2
- expressjs  -v  4.15.0